# Bibliography list items alignement using Natbib alpha style

Tags: natbib

I am using the alpha style with `natbib` (author-year).
My problem is that I am getting the labels aligned right in the Bibliography list items, but I want them left !!
It may be useful to mention that I am using `bibtopic`!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea. But the document is yours. :)

Write the following magic code after you've loaded natbib:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lbibitem}
  {\item[\hfil\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}]}
  {\item[\NAT@anchor{#2}{\NAT@num}\hfill]}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

This redefines the `\@lbibitem` command that's responsible for many things, among which the placement of the label.